# Possible to extend JQueryEventObject in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jquery

I've only just started with Typescript but I'm wondering if it is possible to extend the JQueryEventObject with a new method - I'd like to add a cancel method that sets the event to stop bubbling and propagating.

If my understanding is correct, there is no way to do this using TypeScript because the JQueryEventObject is merely an interface created to provide an intellisense of what is available on the event object provided to an event.  However, I may be wrong and if someone has got a solution, then I'd appreciate someone sharing that with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the typescript definition is an interface, however, you can extend it, and you can also extend the runtime to add the new function.  There are two things that need to be done:

1. make typescript aware of the new function
2. make the new function available at runtime inside jQuery

Here is a code sample that does both:

```
// PatchJquery.ts
// Include the generated .js file for this, after jQuery, in some html file.

/// <reference path="typedef/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

// Runtime patch: Assume jQuery is already defined in the global scope 
// and patch its Event prototype.
jQuery.Event.prototype.cancel = function() {
    console.log("Someone wants me to cancel this event!",this);
}

// Define the extended typescript interface
interface ExtJQueryEventObject extends JQueryEventObject {
    cancel():void;
}

// Test
$(function() {
    var body:JQuery = $("body");
    body.on('click', (e:ExtJQueryEventObject) => {
        e.cancel();
    });
});
```

Note that if you wanted, say, an actual click event, you would need to define an extended interface for JQueryMouseEventObject.  You would need to do this for all of the different JQuery event types.  Alternatively, you could just modify jquery.d.ts to add your new function to BaseJQueryEventObject.

(BTW, jQuery has stopPropagation() and stopImmediatePropagation(), which might do what you want already)

Comment: You don't even need to name the Interface differently, giving it the same name will automatically extend the existing interface.

Comment: Thank you both, I actually ended up doing it as @Anzeo had suggested, without the need for ExtJQueryEventObject and it works fine.  The reason I wanted a cancel event is so that I don't have to keep writing preventDefault(), stopPropagation() and stopImmediatePropagation() as the code behind cancel calls all these and sets cancelBubble to true.